# VimTeX omnicompletion for bibliography

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, plugin-vimtex

Problem with builtin omnicompletion for bibliography. It works on `main.tex`, but not in the chapters.
This is the tree structure:

```
├── chapters
│   ├── actors_behaviour.tex
│   ├── analysis_acts.tex
│   ├── conclusion.tex
│   ├── EU_approach.tex
│   ├── introduction.tex
│   └── terminology_of_data.tex
├── images
│   ├── association_triple.svg
│   ├── data-coop-ecosystem.pdf
│   ├── data_management_solutions.svg
│   ├── dga_pillars
│   ├── dga_pillars.svg
├── main.tex
├── svg-inkscape
│   ├── association_triple_svg-tex.pdf
│   ├── association_triple_svg-tex.pdf_tex
│   ├── data_management_solutions_svg-tex.pdf
│   └── data_management_solutions_svg-tex.
```

The bibliography file is in a parent directory, but that is not the problem.

[Here](https://github.com/enrico223/.config/tree/master/nvim) my Neovim configuration. I don't know if this is the right forum for this question, in case it is not, please tell me where I should post this.

Comment: Vimtex omnicompletion or built-in omnicompletion? If the former, use the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: @romainl I think is the built-in omnicompletion, `<C-X><C-O>`

Comment: If the chapters don’t load the bib file (normal), I’m not sure how any reasonable tool would know to look in the bib file without being told about it. Your question says vimtex… perhaps there is something in its documentation?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble the fact is that it did work, I don't remember what changed to make it not work. I am looking at some issues in the `vimtex` repos, but can't really find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@D.Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) I fixed it. As I said in the comment, the omnicompletion for bibliography used to work without the `\addbibresource{path/to/bib_file}`, now it you have to have it in the files to make it work.